# Retrieve top ranked documents in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, ranking, information-retrieval

Assume that I have a single index with documents that have two computed fields for ranking: `popularity` and `relevance`. Also assume that there is no overlap between documents that should be ranked by `popularity` and that should be ranked by`relevance`. That is, in the system some documents should be ranked by `popularity` and others by `relevance`.

Then I need to retrieve `N` top ranked documents with the requirement that `N1` of them are ranked by `popularity` and `N-N1` are ranked by `relevance`.

Is there a way to do this in Elastic Search with a single request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [multisearch api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) in order to do completely separate queries in one go.